# Missing ')' in validation rule

Tags: validation, validation-rule, compile-error

Hi the title says it all, no clue why I am getting the error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

```
AND( 
    OR(
     ISPICKVAL( StageName , "1 - Prospect"), 
     ISPICKVAL( StageName , "2 - Strategy/Proposal Generation"), 
     ISPICKVAL( StageName , "3 - Proposal Submitted"), 
     ISPICKVAL( StageName , "4 - Negotiation") 
    ), 
    OR(RecordTypeId ="203030",RecordTypeId ="04059596")
    AND(
     MOD(MONTH(CloseDate),3) = 0,// error highlights the comma on this line
     DAY(CloseDate) > 15
    )
)
```

Comment: It identifies the record type, only specific record types should be affected by this validation rule

Comment: Still i suppose a comma is missing after `OR(RecordTypeId ="203030",RecordTypeId ="04059596")`. Yes that is the only issue. I checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your missing a comma after second **OR** condition.

```
AND( 
OR(
 ISPICKVAL( StageName , "1 - Prospect"), 
 ISPICKVAL( StageName , "2 - Strategy/Proposal Generation"), 
 ISPICKVAL( StageName , "3 - Proposal Submitted"), 
 ISPICKVAL( StageName , "4 - Negotiation") 
), 
OR(RecordTypeId ="203030",RecordTypeId ="04059596"),
AND(
 MOD(MONTH(CloseDate),3) = 0,// error highlights the comma on this line
 DAY(CloseDate) > 15
)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a section towards the bottom which is closed with `()`, but doesn't have a function associated with it. It should look like:

```
OR(
   MOD(MONTH(CloseDate),3) = 0,
   DAY(CloseDate) > 15
)
```

Its just a really poorly conveyed message.

---

Its this line:

```
OR(RecordTypeId ="203030",RecordTypeId ="04059596")
```

It needs a `,` after it, since you have more conditions to follow.

```
OR(RecordTypeId ="203030",RecordTypeId ="04059596"),
```

Comment: thanks I forgot to put the AND in the problem above, I updated the code, the error still stands as is

Comment: See edit, youre missing a `,`